# Connect a client app Android to a server written with Sails.js using socket.io

Tags: android, angularjs, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

Here's my situation: i have a server written with sails.js where i have a user model. I have a dashboard where i can see all the users, create new, delete them and so on...Now i want to create an android app where i can get, using socket.io, notification about the events that occour to the user model. 
Example: if i delete a user from my dashboard i want the app to recive a notification from the server that the user has been deleted.

Here's my code for the app:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
//socket instance
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://server_url:port/user");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //set the layout for this activity

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mSocket.on("user", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    mSocket.connect();

    final Button btn_createUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_createUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSocket.connected()) {
                //tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Like i did with the dashboard to connect the socket to the server i did the same thing here, but it seems like the socket doesn't connect, in fact, when i delete a user from the dashboard i get no notification.

Here's the code (that works) i used in my dashboard to connect my socket to the server and listen to updates from the user model:

```
//connect to the server and listen to updates from user model
      io.socket.get('/user', function(data, jwres) {
          $scope.users = data;
          $scope.$apply(); //write users in the table...
      });
      //wait for updates...
io.socket.on('user', function serverResponded (data) {
          if(data.verb == "updated")
          {
              //get the user index in the array and update it
              var index = getIndex(data.id, $scope.users);
              $scope.users[index].online = data.data.online;
              $scope.$apply();
          }
          if(data.verb == "destroyed")
          {
              //get the user index in the array and remove it
              var index = getIndex(data.id, $scope.users);
              $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
              $scope.$apply();
          }
          if(data.verb == "created")
          {
              //simply update the array
              $scope.users.push(data.data);
              $scope.$apply();
          }
      });
```

Now, i think all i'm missing out in the android app is the GET request which automatically subscribe my socket to the model and get notified if something happen...but i don't know hot to do it.

I hope i was clear enough...thank to everyone who will answer me!

PS: i don't want to use AndroidAsync because i need the ultimate version of socket.io!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need it, i found the solution: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2640 here you can find out how to solve the issue! :)